# How to run multiple threads inside loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am currently implementing a task that takes a lot  of time.
Basically, what I want to do is to run multiple tasks inside foreach loop.
I tried using Parallel.ForEach its freezing my UI. I wanna be able to call like 10 uids at a time.

```
foreach (var uid in listBox2.Items)
              {
                  if (StopEmail) break;
                  Application.DoEvents();
                  string jsonstring = GetEmails(uid.ToString(), token);
                  if (jsonstring != null)
                  {
                      label6.Text = " Current UID: " + listBox2.Items.IndexOf(uid);
                      dynamic jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring);
                      string idstt = jsonResponse["email"];
                      if (idstt != null)
                      {
                          listBox3.Items.Add(idstt);
                          label4.Text = "Total Emails: " + listBox3.Items.Count.ToString();

                      }
                  }
              }
```

Here is my Parallel.ForEach Code:

```
var files = listBox2.Items.Cast<String>().ToList();
Parallel.ForEach(files, uid =>
{
    Application.DoEvents();
    string jsonstring = GetEmails(uid.ToString(), token);
    if (jsonstring != null)
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
        {
            label6.Text = " Current UID: " + listBox2.Items.IndexOf(uid);
        }));

        dynamic jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring);
        string idstt = jsonResponse["email"];
        if (idstt != null)
        {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
            {
                listBox3.Items.Add(idstt);
                label4.Text = "Total Emails: " + listBox3.Items.Count.ToString();
            }));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If this is freezing your UI, then you are running the outer part of the foreach on the UI thread.  Try running it on a background worker so your UI thread is free to keep drawing. and then from the background thread try using parallel.ForEach

Comment: is this WPF or Winforms

Comment: @meganaut can you please check my edit of parallel.foreach code.

Comment: @M.kazem Akhgary WinForms

Comment: @SherryMemon The problem is the method that parallel.foreach is running in is on the main or UI thread.  Do a little research on backgroundWorkers to find out how to move that function OFF the main ui thread.

Comment: @meganaut Can't be solved using Threading?

Comment: @SherryMemon a backgroundworker is a form of threading. But you could from your UI thread call your method Async. and then inside that method use the parallel.foreach.  But really you should do a little research on how to program winforms without blocking the UI thread, because it will become more of a problem the further you get in to it.

Comment: There's a special hell for any code that calls `Application.DoEvents()`. It is **only** there for compatibility for VB6 applications upgraded in 2001 when .NET first launched. It should be avoided at all costs as it can introduce very difficult to locate re-entrancy bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the approach I would take - use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "System.Reactive.Windows.Forms").

Then you can do this:

```
var uids = listBox2.Item.Cast<String>().ToArray();

var query =
    from uid in uids.ToObservable()
    from jsonstring in Observable.Start(() => GetEmails(uid, token))
    where jsonstring != null
    select new { uid, jsonstring };

IDisposable subscription =
    query
        .ObserveOn(this)
        .Subscribe(x =>
        {
            label6.Text = " Current UID: " + listBox2.Items.IndexOf(x.uid);
            dynamic jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(x.jsonstring);
            string idstt = jsonResponse["email"];
            if (idstt != null)
            {
                listBox3.Items.Add(idstt);
                label4.Text = "Total Emails: " + listBox3.Items.Count.ToString();
            }
        });
```

The slow part is in the `GetEmails` call so that is all nicely handled in the `query`.

The `.ObserveOn(this)` call marshals the code back to the UI thread for you so no messy `.Invoke` calls needed.

And finally, to end the computation early just call `subscription.Dispose()`.

Comment: Yuhoo! Seems, awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Parallel.ForEach` inside a `Task.Run` call:

```
var files = listBox2.Items.Cast<String>().ToList();
Task task = Task.Run( () => {

    Parallel.ForEach( files, uid =>
    {
        // remove the `Application.DoEvents()` call, it is unnecessary
        // ...
    }

} );
```

It may be a better design to instead return data from the `ForEach` method instead of calling `.Invoke` as well, that way you can use `await` and update the UI a single go when the `ForEach` is complete - but that depends on the nature of your loop and your desired UX.

Comment: How can I make it run like 10 uids at a time. I mean 10 tasks,

Comment: @SherryMemon Why 10 specifically? The `Parallel.ForEach` method will see how many hardware threads your computer has and run the correct number to ensure the list is processed optimally. So you must have a very good reason to override `ForEach`'s thread count.

Comment: I wanna keep checking how many uids are checked and all that. that''s why I am updating UI.

Comment: it's doing a bad behavior like sometime it's jumping on uid 2776 and then jumps on uid 29.